# An example of the set of distances of two points in two different closed sets having no infimum

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

On a problem set for my Analysis in Several Dimensions class (basically real analysis on multivariable functions), I encountered this question:

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, let $C ⊂ X$ be a subset that is closed (with respect to $d$), and let $K ⊂ X$ be a subset that is compact (with the subspace topology induced by $d$). Assume that $C$ and $K$ are disjoint. Prove that there exists $x_0 ∈ K$ and $y_0 ∈ C$ such that for every $x ∈ K$ and for every $y ∈ C$, $d(x_0, y_0) ≤ d(x, y)$. Also find a counterexample if $K$ is assumed to be closed, but not necessarily compact.

I managed to prove the statement itself, but I'm having trouble thinking of counterexamples. I tried playing around with the Cantor set (which doesn't work because it's compact), with the sequence $1/n$, with unions of vanishingly small concentric rings in $\Bbb R^2$, but in all of these cases, the sets $C$ and $K$ are not closed. What am I missing?

Comment: Try the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$ and something that’s closed but unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Example(1). In the reals let $A=N$ and $B=\{n+\frac {1}{n+1} :n\in N\}$.

Example(2). In $R^2$ let $A=\{(x,1/x):x>0\}$ and $B=\{(x,-1/x):x>0\}$.

Example(3). Let $p$ be a point not in $R$. Define a metric  $d$ on $S=R\cup \{p\}$ as follows:

For $x,y\in R$ let $ d(x,y)=|x-y|/(1+|x-y|).$

For $x\in R$ let $d(x,p)=2-d(x,0).$

Then $R$ is closed in $S$ and $\inf_{x\in R}d(x,p)=1,$ but $d(x,p)>1$ for all $x\in R.$

Remark: You cannot get an example like (3) in $R$ alone: If $K$ is a non-empty closed subset of $R$ and $p$ is a real number not in $K$, then for some $s>0$ the compact set $T=K\cap [-s+p,p+s]$ is non-empty. Clearly $x\in K\implies |x-p|\geq \min \{|y-p|: y\in T\}.$